# Are there any similar phrases that are popular in the US to express "penny dropped"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, american-english

I met the phrase **penny dropped** today and learned that it is mainly used in UK.

The *Cambridge Idioms Dictionary* via TheFreeDictionary.com [defines it as](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+penny+drops)

> if you say the penny drops, you mean that you have finally understood something.

Are there any similar ways that are popular in the US to express the same meaning?

Comment: I think one of the more common US ones which means something similar (though not exactly the same) is **the other shoe dropped**.

Comment: "lightbulb moment"?

Comment: "Suddenly, it hit me" might be good as well

Comment: Are you referring to this?: *if you say the penny drops, you mean that you have finally understood something* - http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+penny+drops

Comment: @Josh61, Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your question, I didn't know this UK expression !

Comment: @JohnClifford "penny dropped" is about understanding something, so nothing to do with the other shoe dropping.

Comment: Eureka moment, I'd say.

Comment: @DAVE: I don't think it's exclusively a UK expression.  Certainly it's familiar to this American, though I do admit to reading a lot of Agatha Christie, Terry Pratchett, and other British authors.

Comment: Interesting is that in Dutch the phrase is "the quarter dropped" (het kwartje is gevallen)

Comment: @jAMES, I did read in High school Agatha, but so far I can't remember this expression with a penny. However, I had it with a nickel & a quarter too...

Comment: The equivalent Hebrew expression refers specifically to the tokens used in payphones (before the days of calling cards) - as in, the call finally connected because the money hit the machine inside

Comment: Americans occasionally drop pennies, too.

Comment: I'm accustomed to hearing this as "the ***coin*** dropped".  I interpret this as an allusion to a mechanism that accepts coins (e.g., a pay phone or vending machine).  These machines are notorious for having coins get caught in the chute, so they don't register; jostling the machine often shakes the coin free.  These machines rarely accept pennies.

Comment: This is a common expression to my US ear. Where did you learn it is mainly used in the UK? I believe you, just curious.

Comment: P.S. A vaguely similar phrase (at least in the US) is to ***drop a dime***, which means to report somebody's illegal or improper actions (e.g., to law enforcement or other authorities), perhaps anonymously — since this is best done by phone, and especially a ***pay*** phone (which takes coins).

Comment: Lots of good suggestions, but to my Br ear where they all fall a little short is in the interrogative form: the faint derision implied in 'When's the penny going to drop?' - 'When's the light going to go on?' just doesn't sound the same!

Comment: "The penny dropped" can also be used to poke fun at someone who hasn't realized something that was quite obvious to everyone else, so depending on context  "eureka moment" etc. won't be a good fit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- ***[light-bulb moment](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/light-bulb-moment)***

> A moment of sudden realization, enlightenment, or inspiration

[ODO]

- ***And then, [it hit me!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=It+Hit+Me)***

> That exact moment I finally understood something.

[Urban Dictionary] (for lack of better resources)

Comment: Should "it hit me" be "it hits me" or it's intentionally used like that?

Comment: I think I have the answer now. This ngram tells me the truth. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+hit+me%2C+it+hits+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20hit%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20hits%20me%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @OgrishMan - "It *hit* me" would be the equivalent of sudden realization. (I was breaking my head over a high severity bug but then it **hit me**! StackOverflow!!) "It *hits* me" means that it affects me (Lower wages **hits me** where it hurts the most, my quality of life).

Comment: I've also heard phrases like "then the light came on" or "then a light bulb turned on". [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit) has "hit on a solution" as a similar usage. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hit) has "then it hit me" defined as "occur to", "enter your head", though I'm not sure how reputable TFD is considered.

Comment: Standing in the park I wondered, why does a frisbee appear bigger the closer it gets? And then it hit me.

Comment: @OgrishMan "It hit me" is the past tense of the verb. "It hits me" is the present tense. Both are grammatically correct, but your sentence "The penny *dropped*" is in the past tense. The present tense would not usually be used with this meaning of the phrase, but it could be used with the literal meaning of "dropping a small coin".

Answer (score 33):

You could say that ***[it clicked](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clicked)***.

> *informal* to become suddenly clear: *it finally clicked when her name was mentioned.*

[AHD via TFD]

Answer (score 14):

To [dawn (up) on someone](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dawn+on):

> - Fig. [for a fact] to become apparent to someone; [for something] to be suddenly realized by someone. (Upon is formal and less commonly used than on.)
>
>   - *Then it dawned upon me that I was actually going to have the job. On the way home, it dawned on me that I had never returned your call, so when I got home I called immediately.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

Comment: Is this one popular in the US? If I say it, will most US citizens understand me?

Comment: Yes, it is a common expression, it is also used in the UK though. Compare here : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+dawned+on+me%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cit+dawned+on+me%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20dawned%20on%20me%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20dawned%20on%20me%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm not sure this is an exact match.  The "dropped" phrase refers to gaining an understanding; "it dawned on me" refers to realizing a new fact; perhaps deducing it from information previously known (and understood) information.

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent it means sudden realisation - [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dawn) has "to begin to be perceived or understood".

Answer (score 8):

You might call that a [eureka moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect):

> The eureka effect (also known as the **aha! moment** or **eureka moment**) refers to the common human experience of suddenly understanding a previously incomprehensible problem or concept.

Comment: After "light-bulb moment", this was the next thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 6):

“Finally/[suddenly seeing the light](https://books.google.com/books?id=mMBt6f4G9agC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22saw+the+light%22+%22penny+dropped%22&source=bl&ots=Z_YXLo6-A_&sig=dTS7D8dQ8T3sPnA1pGnVY5en1j8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK_ZnjuLHLAhXCLmMKHTfiAiAQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22saw%20the%20light%22%20%22penny%20dropped%22&f=false)” is another way to describe a “penny-dropping moment.”
(example usage of “I suddenly saw the light!” next to “The penny dropped!”  from ‘Young Children Learning Through Schemas: Deepening the dialogue about learning in the home and in the nursery’ by Katey Mairs, The Pen Green Team, via ‘Google Books’)

[**see the light**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+the+light)
Fig. to understand something clearly at last.
 “After a lot of studying and asking many questions, I finally saw the light.”
“I know that geometry is difficult. Keep working at it. You'll see the light pretty soon.”
(from ‘McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs’ via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’)

**see the light**
1. to understand something clearly, especially after you have been confused about it for a long time
“Sarah used to have very racist views, but I think she's finally seen the light.”
(from ‘Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.’, also via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex, lower on the same page linked above)

Answer (score 3):

"Fell into place"?

He was trying to figure it out, when suddenly **it all fell into place**. It was the Butler, who did it!

Comment: Also, the pieces fell into place. I guess it's a jigsaw puzzle reference?

Answer (score 1):

Have a [**moment of clarity**](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_moment_of_clarity)

Or an [**Epiphany**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_%28feeling%29), also known as [**sudden realization/suddenly realizing**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=epiphany) (JOKE)

Comment: These are valid, although they are very standard English. Saying what something is instead of using an idiom.

Comment: @AJFaraday OP includes the more general tag 'expressions' as well as 'idioms'.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of the idiom, *get the picture*:

> to understand a situation.

Example:

> "The team won two, then lost three, then won two, then lost two, then won three - you *get the picture*?"

It is referring to clarity in tuning old televisions.

([Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+picture))

Comment: To *get the picture* is to gain an understanding of something; it does not convey the *moment* of understanding.

Comment: I don't agree based on the provenance I indicate, but I accept my Minnesotan heritage has put an odd spin on many of the idioms I use.

Comment: @choster - Good point. I think, though, that _suddenly get the picture_ could work nicely, as in: _Suddenly, I got the picture_.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase similar to "seeing the light" is ***the fog cleared***.

Answer (score -1):

[Grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) - 'to understand intuitively or by empathy, to establish rapport with'

Comment: Grok describes a state of affairs, a condition, not a moment.  For example, "Do you grok perl?"  "No, it's all line noise to me".   You don't say "Aha!  I grok it!".  There is no element of "finally, at last" in the work "grok" (in contrast to for example 'a light bulb moment').

Comment: I judged the intuitive understanding of something to be inline with what the OP was looking for.

Comment: OP's link gives an example of usage; in the example, the understanding occurred suddenly. There's no indication that the understanding was "intuitive".

Comment: This is pretty far outside modern American idiom, being derived from Heinlein's half-century old book.

Comment: @Lighthart I would say that it is generally and immediately understood in tech/geek culture, but not in modern America at large.

Answer (score -1):

"The light came on" Would be the closest thing I would think of.

Comment: Please explain why this is the closest thing you can think of.